# install scheduler at runtime

Tags: php, wordpress, cron

I am trying to set a scheduler at runtime, everytime the cron option is updated it will setted the job. I tried and it doesn't work, how to get it to work? Code explanation: everytime the cron option is updated the old scheduler is deleted and it is installed a new one. When the plugin is deactivated it is deleted. I want to add at runtime a schedule with the function dynamic_scheduler_activation.

```
function settings_data_updated($option_name, $value) {
    if ($option_name === 'cron') {
       dynamic_scheduler_activation($value);            
   }
}
add_action('updated_option', 'settings_data_updated', 10, 3);
add_action('added_option', 'settings_data_updated', 10, 2);

add_action ( 'custom_cronjob_hook', 'my_function' );

function dynamic_scheduler_activation($sec) {
   scheduler_deactivation();
   if (!wp_next_scheduled('custom_cronjob_hook')) 
        wp_schedule_event( time(), 'custom', 'custom_cronjob_hook' );
   add_filter('cron_schedules', function () use ($sec) {
   $schedules['custom'] = array(
       'interval' => $sec,
       'display'=> "$sec secs"
   );
   return $schedules;
   });
 }

register_deactivation_hook( __FILE__, 'scheduler_deactivation' );
function scheduler_deactivation() {
    wp_clear_scheduled_hook( 'custom_cronjob_hook' );
}
function my_function() { }
```

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work"? You should explain your expected result, and how the actual result differs from this. Also, the indentation in your code is not uniform; it's hard to tell whether you meant for the `if` block to be just the `wp_schedule_event` line or more.

Comment: "doesn't work" means that when I update the cron option like 5 seconds the function my_function doesn't execute.

Comment: Does the real `my_function` function do anything? What you've shown here is an empty function, which could be running and just not doing anything...